# Docker blank/empty previous bash command

Tags: command-line, bash, docker

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, starting an interactive docker terminal with:

```
docker run --rm -it <image>
```

After typing a few commands, I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to see the last command in history. The prompt remains blank, but typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> again shows the second to last command. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> then works as expected.

The same issue occurs on all my machines. It also seems to be an issue specific to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> because those keys don't work in vim in docker either.

Oddly enough, using the up arrow from the beginning also does as expected. Why is the prompt blank with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>?

Answer (score 4):

See the SO question [How do you attach and detach from Docker's process?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19689048/622049) for the root cause. I can see how it'd be useful to have keys for this in docker, but it's surprising the default chord starts with such a common key combination.

See [Use the Docker command line | Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#configuration-files) for a solution. To summarize that page, create a `.docker/config.json` file in your home directory and use the same default suggested in the docker documentation:

```
{
    "detachKeys": "ctrl-e,e"
}
```

Comment: Oddly, when Docker sees the second `ctrl-p` prefix key it sends *both* to the shell (instead of just one), so the history skips every other entry.